# (Import Error) cant install packages with pip since trying to install gensim.models

Tags: python, pip, importerror

Had to install a number of packages and pip install worked perfectly fine but since trying to install gensim.models (which i think was wrong since it should have been gensim) i cant install either gensim or other packages.

The following error always pops up:

[image]

edit:
after searching for solutions i found this

[image]

my output is Version: 1.12.0
But pip install -U six doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to manually replace the content of the  six file
( in my case under /lib/python3.9/site-packages/six.py )
with the content of

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benjaminp/six/master/six.py